# What is the magnetic field at a distance along the axis of a strictly elliptical solenoid?

Tags: magnetic-fields, inductance

And at what rate does it decay as we move perpendicular to the axis?

Answer (score 1):

Far enough away a coil will look like a dipole.  Dipole fields fall off as one over the distance to the third power.   (Far enough away is roughly a few times the size of the coil.)